# How to serve a symfony app on 192.168.x.x?

Tags: symfony

When I launch the command php app/console server:run my application is served on localhost:8000 and isn't accessible with my local ip address 192.168.0.41:8000.

How can I do that?

I'm under MacOSX Maverick and I don't want to use apache or nginx. I just want a simple step by step to do it with the PHP built-in embedded server.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: These links may be useful, they indicate that you just specify the listening address and port on the command line when you start the web server.: [php-5-4-built-in-webserver](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-built-in-webserver). and [manual: features.commandline.webserver.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). I do not run PHP 5.4+ here so it is untested.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If someone search the command is:

```
php app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: `php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0` already does the trick. Port 8000 is the default port.

Answer (score 8):

for Symfony 4 you can run

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

Answer (score 2):

The command is:

```
php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```

..Note "bin" instead of "app" before the slash.

Comment: I'm using symfony 3.1.7